# Typescript: What exactly refers the type "{[name:string]: string}" to?

Tags: typescript

I looked into some TypeScript source code lately and came across a property typed like this:

```
private _properties: {[name:string]: string};
```

I asked myself what this type refers to? What is it exactly?

I thought it would be an object where key and value need to be string.

But I tried it in the TypeScript Playground and saw that something like

```
this._properties['name'] = 5;
```

is also valid. So what's the complete explanation of this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you're right the first time.  _properties is a map of `string` to `string`.

[Here's an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20_properties%3a%20%7B%5Bname%3astring%5D%3a%20string%7D%20=%20%7B%7D;%0D%0A_properties%5B%27name%27%5D%20=%205;) on the TypeScript Playground demonstrating the expected error.

If you can link an example where that statement is valid we can figure out why.

Comment: Don't know why there was no error, maybe I didn't see it.